# Initializing a controlled field after construction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am trying to initialize a controlled field in react, but I don't know the initial value during construction.

My understanding is that even if you do a setState, which causes a re-render, this won't change the value of the control - I'm not sure why though.

So, the following won't work:

```
componentDidMount() {

   ...   // code to get value

   this.setState({ value: "hello world" });
   return ( <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
}
```

Instead, I tried to render the input in the setState callback - to ensure that the value is set:

```
componentDidMount() {

   ...   // code to get value

   this.setState({ value: "hello world" }, this.renderInput);
}

renderInput = () => {
   this.input = ( <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
}
```

Note: my form includes {this.input)

In the second example, my form renders perfectly, and the input is initialized.  However, then the onChange function is called, even though it correctly updates the state, the state change is not picked up - my input field is frozen, as if there was no onChange at all.

This really has me stumped and I'd love to know if there is a way to initialize my fields without being forced to call a potentially slow function inside the construction.

Comment: Why are you returning an `<input>` from `componentDidMount()`? What is your `this.handleChange` doing? can you include your `render()` function?

Comment: Agreed, I don't think returning an element from `componentDidMount` will ever do anything.

Comment: Also we definitely need to see `handleChange`, since that's probably where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: On re-read, I realized your code effectively does the same thing my original answer suggested (but in a very non-idiomatic way). Probably the real issue is in your `handleChange`, but I'll leave the original answer since it shows a more idiomatic way of waiting to render the field.

---

(original answer)

Simplest solution would be to not render the `<input>` until you know its initial value. Use something like this at the appropriate spot in `render()`:

```
{ typeof this.state.value === 'string' ?
  <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} /> :
  null }
```

Drawback of this approach: if there are other elements in the form, they'll "jump" when this field appears, which isn't great.

To avoid jumping, you could wait to render *any* of the form controls until all initial values are available. Add a property `this.state.isLoading` which is initially true, then set to false when loading finishes. (For convenience, the code sample assumes you have a function `getInitialValue()` which returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), but you could do something similar with callbacks or some other construct.)

```
componentDidMount() {
  getInitialValue().then((initialValue) => {
    this.setState({ value: initialValue, isLoading: false });
  });
}

render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading)
    return null; // or something like <div>Loading...</div>

  // else, return normal stuff
}
```